# How to pass a dynamically allocated array to fortran from julia

Tags: fortran, julia

I am trying to call some fortran (f90) code from julia, but I can't seem to get fortran to understand dynamically allocated arrays passed from julia. This fortran code:

```
MODULE myModule
    implicit none
    public Func
CONTAINS

subroutine Func(A,B)
    integer*8, intent(inout) :: A(3)
    integer*8, intent(inout) :: B(:)
    integer :: i

    write(*,*) "size of A"
    write(*,*) size(A)

    write(*,*) "A"
    do i=1,3
        write(*,*) A(i)
    enddo

    write(*,*) "size of B"
    write(*,*) size(B)

    write(*,*) "B"
    do i=1,size(B)
        write(*,*) B(i)
    enddo

end subroutine Func
end module
```

called by this julia code

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]

ccall((:__mymodule_MOD_func,"./test.so"), Nothing ,(Ref{Int64},Ref{Int64}), A,B)
```

produces this result

```
 size of A
           3
 A
                    1
                    2
                    3
 size of B
           0
 B
```

I would expect size(B) to be 3.

Is there any way to make this work without changing the fortran code? I know that I could rewrite the fortran code to include the dimension of the array in the function call, but I would prefer to be able to call fortran code that has already been written in a similar fashion to the example I provided.

Comment: You can't do that magically with plain ccall from Julia. For assumed shape arrays, such info ought to be passed somehow. [This might be a good read](https://thinkingeek.com/2017/01/14/gfortran-array-descriptor/). You might be able to create some intermediate layer, but one way or another you need to pass that info from Julia side.

Comment: @mlt, the array descriptor for gfortran has changed. The url you posted applies to versions older that 9.1.

Comment: @Steve Thanks! I haven't used Fortran in a while. My point was that doing that would be messy and non-portable. I guess you confirmed my point.

Comment: @mlt, the recent descriptor change was in fact motivated by portability.  Technical Specification ISO/IEC TS 29113:2012 defines the dope vector.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a fortran wrapper function that takes in the size of dynamic arrays passed in.

```
subroutine wrapFunc(A,B,Bdim)
    integer*8, intent(inout) :: A(3)
    integer*8, intent(inout) :: Bdim
    integer*8, intent(inout) :: B(Bdim)
    call Func(A,B)    

end subroutine wrapFunc
```

This allows me to not have to alter the existing fortran code.